# Solaris: Is it OK to disable font services?

Tags: solaris, service

Is it OK to disable these services?

```
# svcs -l '*font*'
fmri         svc:/application/font/stfsloader:default
name         Standard Type Services Framework (STSF) Font Server loader
enabled      true
state        online
next_state   none
state_time   Sun May 30 17:58:14 2010
restarter    svc:/network/inetd:default

fmri         svc:/application/font/fc-cache:default
name         FontConfig Cache Builder
enabled      true
state        online
next_state   none
state_time   Sun May 30 17:58:15 2010
logfile      /var/svc/log/application-font-fc-cache:default.log
restarter    svc:/system/svc/restarter:default
dependency   require_all/none svc:/system/filesystem/local (online)
dependency   require_all/refresh file://localhost/etc/fonts/fonts.conf (online)
dependency   require_all/none file://localhost/usr/bin/fc-cache (online)
#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing really uses stfsloader - the STSF project died shortly after the Solaris 10 release,
and it should be completely safe to disable.

The fc-cache service runs at boot to update the fontconfig caches and exits.   Disabling it will just reduce performance and increase memory usage of any software using fontconfig,
like the GNOME desktop and Firefox.   If you never run any GUI applications on the system,
either locally or displayed remotely, and never do any text rendering in webapps or similar services using fontconfig, you can probably disable it without any effect, but what's the point of doing that?